# Regex for a custom 'HTTP GET style' request

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to parse (Java) a custom GET style request, and I'd like to do that through a regular expression.
The request is formatted like:

```
GET myCommand?parameter1=value&parameter2=value&parameter3=value&parameter4=value
```

The number of params is variable, but at least one param is required.

Can someone help me with this regex?

Comment: What do you mean by "parse"? Do you mean extract the command name and name/value pairs each as separate pieces of data?

Comment: Why not use a query string libary and boolean expressions etc. to validate it?
Would be the neater and more scaleable solution.

Comment: @Bohemian: yes, that's exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to parse it all into java variables using 4 lines:

```
String command = input.replaceAll("(^\\w+ )|(\\?.*)", "");
Map<String, String> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
for (String pair : input.replaceFirst(".*?\\?", "").split("&"))
    params.put(pair.split("=")[0], pair.split("=")[1]);
```

Note that using a `LinkedHashMap` iterates in input order.

Here's a little test using your input (modified a little to have distinct values):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String input = "GET myCommand?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2&parameter3=value2&parameter4=value4";
    String command = input.replaceAll("(^\\w+ )|(\\?.*)", "");
    Map<String, String> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    for (String pair : input.replaceFirst(".*?\\?", "").split("&"))
        params.put(pair.split("=")[0], pair.split("=")[1]);
    System.out.println("Command=" + command);
    System.out.println("Params=" + params);
}
```

Output:

```
Command=myCommand
Params={parameter1=value1, parameter2=value2, parameter3=value2, parameter4=value4}
```

Answer (score 0):

`GET myCommand\?([a-z0-9]+)=(.+)(&([a-z0-9]+)=(.+))*`

Now just replace `[a-z0-9]+` with a regex for valid identifiers, `.+` with a regex for valid values, and escape as required by your language of choice, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Following is regex that will work with any request URL with query parameters: `.+?(\?((\w+?=.+?)&)*\w+?=.+)?$`

Here `.+?` is matching string before query parameters. Let break regex: `(\?((\w+?=.+?)&)*\w+?=.+)?`

`((\w+?=.+?)&)*` represents zero or more key-value pairs joined with `&`
`\w+?=.+` represents last key-value pair

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need more help.